# SVG with mask as background-image of HTML element

Tags: css, svg, background-image, mask, css-transforms

I want to use an SVG as the `background-image` of an HTML element. However, this fails when I use a mask anywhere in the SVG. When `mask="url(#m)"` is removed in the code below, the SVG is displayed as the background image without issue.

HTML:

```html
<div>Some element.</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
// The following SVG is correctly rendered as a standalone SVG file, but not in `background-image`.
const svg = `<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <mask id="m" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </mask>
  <rect mask="url(#m)" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
</svg>`;

document.querySelector("div").style.backgroundImage = `url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(svg)}`;
```

([JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/frq05312/))

Result:
[image: no background image]

Expected result:
[image: intended background image]

Is it possible to have SVG masks in a `background-image` like this? If not, what's the reason?

Relatedly, the background image also fails to display if I add `style="transform: translate(0)"` to the `svg` (though other styles, like `style="background-color: blue"` work without issue). Is it possible to use `transform` in an SVG `background-image`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for the data URL

```
document.querySelector("div").style.backgroundImage = `url('data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(svg)}')`;
```

is what you want

```js
const svg = `<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <mask id="m" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </mask>
  <rect mask="url(#m)" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
</svg>`;

document.querySelector("div").style.backgroundImage = `url('data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(svg)}')`;
```

```html
<div>Some element.</div>
```